# Sinc function vs Dirichlet kernel

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

What is the relationship between the `sinc` function and the `Dirichlet kernel`:

$$
\operatorname {sinc} (x)={\frac {\sin(x)}{x}}
$$

$$
D_n(x)=\sum_{k=-n}^n
e^{ikx}=1+2\sum_{k=1}^n\cos(kx)=\frac{\sin\left(\left(n +1/2\right) x \right)}{\sin(x/2)}
$$

I'm primarily interested in their applications in Harmonic Analysis.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of the Dirichlet kernel as a periodic version of the sinus cardinalis: one the one hand $D_n$ is obviously periodic (with period $2\pi$). On the other hand, if $n$ is large and $x$ is small holds:

$$ 
\frac{\sin\left(\left(n +1/2\right) x \right)}{\sin(x/2)}
\approx 
\frac{\sin\left(\left(n +1/2\right) x \right)}{x/2}
=
\frac{(n+1/2)}{2}\text{sinc}((n+1/2)x)
$$

I.e. locally around $0$ it looks like a scaled sinc function. The same argument holds of course for any point $x=2\pi k$, $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Convolution of a function with the Dirichlet kernel produces the partial sum representing the function after forward and inverse Fourier transform. Does it make any sense to call such operation a decomposition by sinc functions?

Comment: @Hyperplane: I think the factor of 1/2 in the final term should be 2. Also, doesn't this approximation only depend on x being small? It seems to me it should be valid for any value of n, not just large n.

Answer (score 1):

Cf. this article [What is the sum of a sinc function series sampled periodically](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2767564/what-is-the-sum-of-a-sinc-function-series-sampled-periodically) .
This article excellently describes the relation between the sum of a periodic sinc sampling function and the Dirichlet kernel function.